# LINQ many to many hell - querying where CONTAINS ALL

Tags: linq-to-sql, many-to-many, contains

I have a many to many relationship as follows:

**Products**
ProductID
Description

**ProductFeatures**
ProductFeatureID
ProductID
FeatureID

**Features**
FeatureID
Description

Any Product can have many Features.

I then come along with an iQueryable called "SearchFeatures" which contains two particular Feature objects that I want to search on.

I want to find the Products which have ALL of these Features!

E.g. something like this would be nice:

```
return db.Products.Where(x => x.Features.ContainsAll(SearchFeatures));
```

What is the cleanest way to achieve this using LINQ?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
IQueryable<Products> products = db.Products;
foreach (var feature in SearchFeatures)
{
    Feature tmpFeature = feature;
    products = products
        .Where(x=>x.ProductFeatures.Any(y=>y.FeatureID == tmpFeature.FeatureID));
}
```

Comment: This is a good solution if SearchFeatures is a local collection.

Comment: Francisco you absolute legend.

David B very very good point, because this was exactly my situation. SearchFeatures was a local collection and thus I was getting LINQ errors with the other approaches because of that. Something about not being able to cross-query a combination of local and database/committed collections.

Francisco's solution deals with this perfectly and my code is running like a dream. Many thanks to both of you.

Comment: Yes! This is exactly what I was looking for! This is an alternative way to build a real ContainsAll (which is not supported by linq-to-sql) thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

```
from item in db.Products
where item.ProductFeatures.Where(x=>featIdList.Contains(x.FeatureId)).Count() == featIdList.Count
select item
```

This should do it. featIdList is a list of the feature ids that you're looking for

Comment: Thanks Mike, another solution along the lines of the others and I think it would work well assuming my collection wasn't local.

Comment: @Aaron This should work with a local collection. I've successfully used it before. Just make sure that featIdList is a list of Ids and not a list of features

Answer (score 1):

Something like this ought to work

```
public partial class Product
{
    public IEnumerable<Feature> Features
    {
        get
        {
            return ProductFeatures.SelectMany(pf => pf.Feature);
        }
    }
}

Products.Where(p => SearchFeatures.All(sf => p.Features.Count(f => f.ID == sf.ID) > 0));
```

Comment: This was working well for me, except I failed to mention that my SearchFeatures was a local collection, so I was then getting errors. But tidy solution and still deserves a point - thanks.

Comment: @Aaron: yes, as you can see in that last line of code, it's not really inside any context at all. perhaps the formatting is misleading, but anyhow, that call was meant to be wherever you're currently making the call, and `SearchFeatures` may be any local variable in that scope.

Comment: Thanks David. Your code does look very clean, but I am still getting this error "Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementation of query operators except the Contains() operator.". I just plugged it in a second time to give it another try, because I like the simplicity of this solution, but it isn't happy and does give me the error.

Specifically, this is my code:
SearchResults = SearchResults.Where(p => search.SearchFeatures.All(sf => p.Features().Count(f => f.PropertyFeatureID == sf.PropertyFeatureID) > 0));

Comment: Note also I had used my own existing Features() method rather than your "public IEnumerable<Feature> Features". So I just tried to create your "public IEnumerable<Feature> Features" to see if that made a difference, but then I got some really casting/types error where it wouldn't let me create it. Any other thoughts?

Comment: @Aaron: oh, i see, yeah, i guess it doesn't translate to LINQ-to-SQL. sorry bout that. it'd be a handy solution for LINQ-to-objects =)

Answer (score 1):

```
IQueryable<Product> query = db.Products
  .Where(p => SearchFeatures
    .All(sf =>
      p.ProductFeatures.Select(pf => pf.Feature).Contains(sf)
    )
  );
```

Comment: This solution is really elegant, I will hang onto it for cases where SearchFeatures isn't Local. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it did not existed in 2010, but now you can do something like:

```
var myArray = new[] { 2, 3 };
q = myArray.Aggregate(q, (current, myArrayItem) => current.Where(x => x.Producs.Any(y => y.Id == myArrayItem)));
```